# Exporting Visualforce to Excel including RichText fields

Tags: visualforce, excel

Another VF excel issue. I'm outputting RichText fields in my VisualForce export like this:

```
<apex:column>     
                            <apex:facet name="header">Transaction Facts</apex:facet>    
                            <apex:outputText value="{! a.DRC_Account__r.Transaction_Facts__c }"  escape="true"/>
                        </apex:column>

                        <apex:column>     
                            <apex:facet name="header">Transaction Updates</apex:facet>  
                            <apex:outputText value="{! a.DRC_Account__r.Transaction_Updates__c }"  escape="true"/> 
                        </apex:column>
```

When output as PDF or HTML it's fine, however when exporting to Excel I get stuff like this

```
â¢ Expecting to receive detailed information on the opportunity this week
```

Comment: The problem is most likely related to how Salesforce exports to Excel.

If you were to save the exported Excel file to disk and open it in a text editor you would find it is using HTML tables to hold the data rather than the native Excel file format. Excel in turn is interpreting that HTML table into cell data.

I see you have `escape="true"` on the apex:outputText elements. That seems like a good start. 

What do the RichText fields look like in the text editor? Are there other charaters that need to be HTML encoded?

Comment: thanks Dan, not sure exactly what will be in the Rich text. Most likely bullets will be the main formatting I thnk

Comment: Cracked it @DanielBallinger - see my answer. Glad I didn't need to get into encoding. Thanks for responding and supporting.

Answer (score 4):

Ok this is the working solution

```
<apex:page controller="AccountReportConfiguratorController"  
        contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=Windows-1252#Report.xls " 
        standardstylesheets="false" 
        language="en-US"
        showHeader="false"
    sidebar="false"
        readOnly="true"
        cache="true"
        >
```

The critical piece is this charset=Windows-1252